# Improper PDF file copy using C

Tags: c, pdf, mupdf, file-copying

I have written a code in C wherein I copy the contents of PDF file from one location to other for further processing. What I did is:

Open the file in binary read mode

```
if ((fp = fopen(argv[6],"rb")) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Can't open input file %s\n",argv[6]);
        goto out;
}
```

Then I save the contents of the PDF file to a temporary location

```
/* save the contents for the file to a temporary location */
  tempfp = fopen(CUPS_IPTEMPFILE, "wb");
  while ((n = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZ, fp)) > 0) {
    count = fwrite(buf, 1, BUFSIZ, tempfp);
  }
  fclose(tempfp);
```

I am using MuPDF to open the file; although MuPDF is able to display the file correctly, it gives the following error on the terminal:

```
$ mupdf cupsiptempfile.pdf 
error: cannot find startxref
warning: trying to repair broken xref
```

If I use Okular to display the same file, I DO NOT get any error

```
$ okular cupsiptempfile.pdf
okular(12821)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(12821)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(12821)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(12821)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
okular(12821)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
```

Why there is difference here ? Am I doing something wrong with the copying part ?

Additional Info: When I open the original PDF file using MuPDF, it gives NO error.

Please feel free to ask any further information you want.

Comment: When you copy you write BUFSIZ characters but you might not have read BUFSIZ characters - the variable n is there to tell you how many characters were read so that is how many you should write.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Yes, you are right. That solved the problem. Silly me, I didn't notice that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
while ((n = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZ, fp)) > 0) {
  count = fwrite(buf, 1, BUFSIZ, tempfp);
}
```

When you copy the file you write BUFSIZ characters out but you might not have read BUFSIZ characters in - the variable n is there to tell you how many characters were read so you should only write those n characters back out.  It should probably look like this:

```
while ((n = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZ, fp)) > 0) {
  count = fwrite(buf, 1, n, tempfp);
}
```